# Query to convert datetime column to a different time zone

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I am trying to assemble a date, time & time zone and then convert it to UTC time zone.

In the query below an error is created with the database field which stores the time zone --- namely t.timezone

The value of t.timezone is Asia/Tokyo .  All other time zones are in a similar format.

```
select (select CONCAT( DATE(m.last_mailing at time zone 'utc' + INTERVAL '1 day'), ' ', MAKE_TIME(m.email_delivery_hour::int, 0, 0))::timestamp with time zone t.timezone) at time zone 'utc' FROM acts2301_membership.member_subscriptions m INNER JOIN acts2301_email_queue.timezone t ON (m.timezone_reference = t.reference) WHERE m.subscription_reference = '514';
```

Comment: What timezone is your server set to? What timezone is `m.last_mailing` stored in? What specific data does `t.timezone` refer to? Is that the time zone of `m.last_mailing`? Please elaborate, as this is all necessary to give you a proper answer.

Comment: m.last_mailing is timestamp without time zone

Comment: t.timezone has values in the format America/Barbados

Comment: See `pg_timezone_names` for recognized time zone strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below is a query that executes, following the logic in your question. However, much depends on how the time zones of the various pieces of data and your server are set (see also my comment on your question), so you may find you have to tweak where you specify `t.timezone` and where `UTC`:

```
SELECT ((date_trunc('day', (m.last_mailing AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamp) + 
         interval ('1 day') +
         (m.email_delivery_hour::int::text || ':00:00')::time
        )::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE t.timezone
       )::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
FROM acts2301_membership.member_subscriptions m 
JOIN acts2301_email_queue.timezone t ON m.timezone_reference = t.reference
WHERE m.subscription_reference = '514';
```

Also notice the beauty of proper code formatting...

Comment: The query is being assembled in Doctrine.  I am receiving the error:  Expected known function, got 'date_trunc'

Comment: [`date_trunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) is a built-in function, but perhaps the `AT TIME ZONE` clause interferes; see updated answer.

Comment: Incidentally, you are much better off to create a view from the above query (without the filter `m.subscription_reference = '514'`) and then use that view as an entity in Doctrine. PostgreSQL has far more options for building complex queries than any framework like Doctrine, HQL, ActiveRecord, etc.

Comment: But the query runs just fine in PostgreSQL 9.3, with and without the explicit cast. The function has been around for ages (at least since 8.4). Which version of PG are you using?

Comment: I am going to investigate using a View